# Difference between Press and Tap touch action in Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I want to know the difference between Tapping and pressing on an element while using Appium Driver.

I was able to understand the difference between Click and Tap but not able to clear my head about tap and press. Only difference I was able to ascertain was tap works with both positions and element but press seems to work only with position.

But even then I can use tap to handle both position clicks and element clicks. Why do we need press explicitly ?
They seem to perform the same function on UI. Can someone please explain me a use case where we need to go explicitly for tap and not press and vice-versa.

Below is the code I am using for both :

**Tapping:**

```
t.tap(tapOptions().withElement(ElementOption.element(MY_WEBELEMENT))).perform();
```

**Pressing:**

```
t.press(PointOption.point(0, 1200)).release().perform();
```

I am new to Appium testing and still working on improving these basics. Feel free to guide me to any existing documentation in place as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Tap` and `Press` both works on Element and Coordinate. Have a look.

Suppose I have this Mobile element, coordinates and duration.

```
MobileElement myElement;
    int xPoint, int yPoint;
    int duration = XXXX; //in miliseconds
```

**Tap on Element:**

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(myElement))).perform();
```

**Tap on Coordinates:**

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).tap(point(xPoint, yPoint)).perform();
```

**Tap on Element using coordinates relative to element:**

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(myElement, xPoint, yPoint))).perform();
```

**LongPress on Element:**

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(myElement))).release().perform();
```

**LongPress on Element with Duration:**

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(myElement)).withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(duration))).release().perform();
```

**LongPress on coordinates:**

```
new TouchAction(localdriver).longPress(point(xPoint, yPoint)).release().perform();
```